# Xna menu items transparent

Tags: c#, menu, xna, background-color, alpha

Trying to create a game in Xna but i have stumbled upon a problem that i cannot seem to figure out.

What i'm trying to do is to draw a menu at the top of the screen, and it shows up. But I'm having a weird problem.
All of the menu items are alpha even though the only place i specify something to be alpha is the background to the menu, is there something obvious that i'm missing here?

[image]

```
public static void draw(SpriteBatch sb,SpriteFont font,GraphicsDevice gd)
    {
        foreach (string item in menuItems)
        {
            MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();
            rect.drawRectangle(gd, sb, new Rectangle(0, 0, gd.Viewport.Width, 35), new Color(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.6f));
            if((ms.X > startPos && ms.X < startPos + (int)font.MeasureString(item).X) && (ms.Y > 10 && ms.Y < 30))
            {
                if(ms.LeftButton != ButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    sb.DrawString(font, item, new Vector2(startPos, 10), Color.Black);
                    sb.DrawString(font, item, new Vector2(startPos + 1, 11), Color.Gray);
                }else
                {
                    sb.DrawString(font, item, new Vector2(startPos, 10), Color.Black);
                    sb.DrawString(font, item, new Vector2(startPos + 1, 11), Color.DarkGray);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                sb.DrawString(font, item, new Vector2(startPos, 10), Color.Black);
                sb.DrawString(font, item, new Vector2(startPos + 1, 11), Color.White);
            }

            startPos += (10 + (int)font.MeasureString(item).X);
        }
        startPos = 10;
    }
```

rect class:

```
public static void drawRectangle(GraphicsDevice graphics,SpriteBatch sb,Rectangle rect,Color color)
        {
            Texture2D pixel = new Texture2D(graphics, 1, 1);
            Color[] colorData = {color};
            pixel.SetData<Color>(colorData);
            sb.Draw(pixel, rect, color);
        }
```

I have tried to create a new color with no alpha, but i get the same results.

Comment: That font you use, maybe beacuse image resize, but text looks like `Öptions` and `Člose` ...

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!
Had to move

```
rect.drawRectangle(gd, sb, new Rectangle(0, 0, gd.Viewport.Width, 35), new Color(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,0.6f));
```

Outside the loop.